# Regex for string with optional quotes

Tags: regex

I'm trying to break apart a string I'm getting from a telnet service which puts in quotes either end of a filename has white space in it, and doesn't include the quotes if there are no white space present. All the other fields are delimited by spaces so no real issue there.

I'm trying (maybe too ambitiously!) to get the whole lot out in Regex groups. Not that it has much bearing on it, but I'm using Perl.

An example of a quoted string is:

> "RAW Superleague backchat 0907 1531" movie/DV/DV100 63173952000 576000 15:21:35:24 16:34:43:01

and an unquoted string might be:

> F0736584_02 movie/DV/DV100 9172224000 576000 16:04:19:00 16:14:55:24

I'm using the regex:

> /^"?(.*)"$?\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)/

which returns the string with quotes very nicely in groups, but doesn't return the second without quotes. I thought that the optional flag would handle this, but it seems not. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because the second line doesn't start with a whitespace. Try this:

```
/^"?(.*)"$?\s?(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)/
             ^----------- new
```